# grep: constructing a regex pattern to exclude several groups

Tags: grep

I have a folder with three files:

```
$ ls

aaa.txt abc.txt def.txt
```

If I want to grep the output excluding the `abc.txt` file I can do:

```
$ ls | grep -v 'abc'

aaa.txt
def.txt
```

If I want to exclude two files I can do:

```
$ ls | grep -v 'abc' | grep -v 'def'

aaa.txt
```

But how can I do this using one regex and one `grep` invocation?

This does not work:

```
$ ls | grep -v '[(abc)(def)]'
```

neither does this:

```
$ ls | grep -v "abc|def"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ERE(Extended Regular Expression) pattern for the alternation match `|` which is not enabled by default in BRE (which `grep` uses by default)

```
grep -vE "abc|def"
```

or use the extended `grep`, i.e. `egrep` which enables the ERE by default

```
egrep -v "abc|def"
```